# Trying to echo an image in Php, cant find src

Tags: php, image, echo

i just started learning Php, right now im trying to convert a HTML page to a Wordpress Theme. I have trouble trying to display images...
In my HTML page i have imgs like:

```
<img class="mainlogoclean" src="images/akbarlogoclean.png"/>
```

When i tried to change it with php my page just stop working:

```
<img class="mainlogoclean" src="<?php echo /images/akbarlogoclean.png ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to echo a string for it to work properly. 
i.e. have  /images/akbarlogoclean.png inside single/double quotes.
You can learn more about how echo works [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

The code could be written in following ways

```
<img class="mainlogoclean" src="<?php echo "/images/akbarlogoclean.png" ?>"/>
```

Or you could also try the shorthand version of using echo

```
<img class="mainlogoclean" src="<?="/images/akbarlogoclean.png" ?>"/>
```

Both of these give the following output

```
<img class="mainlogoclean" src="/images/akbarlogoclean.png"/>
```

Comment: Thanks!, the page doesnt go down now, but still doesnt load the images.

Comment: Have you tried checking the console, maybe the image source is not pointing to the correct image. You can also check the source code of your page for the same.

Comment: Has you said for some reason it didnt find the image, in html everything works fine. Now that im localhosting with wordpress it doesnt load it "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: Clearly, WordPress is not able to find the image. Look for where the index.php file of WordPress is. Try placing the images folder in the same folder, (where index.php of your current project is).
When using HTML, the root directory is defined by your OS, whereas in local server by the server